# Function gen_frames raises exception thus flask application dies. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

**Introduction**:
I have created a Web App using Flask where my client can view the live cameras. Everything is working properly but when the client changes the camera or reload the page it raises **RuntimeError generator ignored GeneratorExit** which stops the flask app from running via Gurnicorn. However, the weird thing is when running using **flask run** locally exception is not raised and the application is running smoothly.

**Goal**: Is to run the flask app using Gurnicorn and Nginx without reloading the flask app on error (As when error raises flask automatically reload and the user gets logged out.)

**When the first user login into the page it loads the first video:**

```
@blueprint.route('/video_feed/<string:unitID>')
@login_required
def video_feed(unitID):
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    client = Client.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
    unit = Unit.query.filter_by(unitID=unitID).first()
    if (unit.clientID == client.clientID):
        print(
            "thread was not found alive and tried to start, hope it runs!", file=sys.stderr)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return Response(gen_frames(unit), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    else:
        return not_found_error("e")
```

**Following is the function to generate video from RTSP stream:**:

```
    def find_camera(unit):

    cameras = ["rtsp://"+unit.camerausername +
               ":password@example.com:"+unit.cameraport]
    return cameras[0]


def gen_frames(unit):
    cam = find_camera(unit)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
    print("reached gen_frames function", file=sys.stderr)

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        success, frame = cap.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            try:
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                frame = buffer.tobytes()
                # concat frame one by one and show result
                yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n' b'Content-Length: ' + f"{len(frame)}".encode() + b'\r\n' b'\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
                time.sleep(0.05)
            except GeneratorExit:
                print("Gen-Error!", file=sys.stderr)
                continue
```

**Please find the error output as below**:

```
    gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 600 --workers=5 --threads=5 run:app
[2021-05-31 11:28:40 +1000] [55217] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-05-31 11:28:40 +1000] [55217] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (55217)
[2021-05-31 11:28:40 +1000] [55217] [INFO] Using worker: threads
[2021-05-31 11:28:40 +1000] [55219] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55219
[2021-05-31 11:28:40 +1000] [55220] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55220
[2021-05-31 11:28:40 +1000] [55221] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55221
[2021-05-31 11:28:41 +1000] [55222] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55222
[2021-05-31 11:28:41 +1000] [55223] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 55223
thread was not found alive and tried to start, hope it runs!
reached gen_frames function
Gen-Error!
[2021-05-31 11:29:11 +1000] [55223] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 326, in handle_request
    resp.write(item)
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 346, in write
    util.write(self.sock, arg, self.chunked)
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 285, in write
    return write_chunk(sock, data)
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 280, in write_chunk
    sock.sendall(chunk)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 333, in handle_request
    respiter.close()
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 510, in close
    callback()
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 528, in close
    self.response.close()
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
Gen-Error!
Exception ignored in: <generator object gen_frames at 0x7f507c753ac0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chirag/dev/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 278, in handle
    self.log.debug("Closing connection. %s", e)
RuntimeError: generator ignored GeneratorExit
```

**This is what I think the issue is:**
When the client changes the video, the previous stream is not closing properly, thus raising exceptions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to implement as follows :-

main.py

```
#Import necessary libraries
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
#Initialize the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def gen_frames():  
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

For Reference you can also visit :- https://towardsdatascience.com/video-streaming-in-web-browsers-with-opencv-flask-93a38846fe00

in this above blog the teh above code is given in detail.

Comment: I referred to this blog and replicated the same. However, while adding more cameras and the feature of changing the camera apps app crashes. There's something I missing but don't know what.

Comment: What kind of OS and IDE u re using ??

Comment: Please read about [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Simply adding a link to the source is not enough. You should make it clear in the answer that this is ***NOT*** your own code

Comment: @sanjayprajapati Initially I started with the same code but when working with multiply cameras and users changing the video (camera feed) breaks the gen_frames function and thus application dies.